# Salesforce Flow Opportunity to Order Errors

Tags: upsert, visual-flows

I have an interesting workflow and maybe that is what needs to change. Right now I have Shopify front end and am using Zapier to take orders from Shopify and create accounts in Salesforce as well as creating closed opportunities.

I'm trying to use [Generate orders](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5iwREAR) to turn the closed opportunities into orders automatically.

Running the Opportunity to Order flow always generates the following: An error occurred at element Create_Order.

> UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED --- ERRORS :
>   (INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE) Order: bad field names on
>   insert/update call: OpportunityId --- for SFDC record with ID : null,

I'm not too familiar with salesforce so I'm not sure where to look to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In your flow, are you setting the field OpportunityID?
If yes & since you are using upsert, the id field should not be set and the external id field should be set.